# Line of code partially covered in Ms Test

Tags: c#, mstest

I have following line of code:

```
return (teacher = "Y" || (student = "Y" && TeacherStudent(enty)));

private bool TeacherStudent(ICmpEntity enty)
{
   return (abc.Field("id").Value() != "N");
}
```

Test like:
teacher = Y, student = Y and id = N.

But problem is this line of code is only partially getting covered? Even though TeacherStudent method is covered 100%

```
return (teacher = "Y" || (student = "Y" && TeacherStudent(enty)));
```

Is there a way to tell what part of condition is not covered in MS Test? Or any idea why this condition is partially covered?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create 2 tests, for both parts of your condition clause. If `teacher = "Y"` , this would prevent to evaluate the second part of the clause.